# Creating table sections with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to drive the data for my `UITableViewController`. A simplified version of the managed object I am fetching looks like this (well for example):

```
Person:
-(BOOL)hasPet;
-(BOOL)hasDog;
```

Basically, I want my table to only show those `Person` objects who have a pet. So that's simple, I can use a predicate. Now, for those who `hasPet == YES`, I want to put them in the table in 2 sections, first section `hasDog == YES`, and the second is `hasDog == NO`. This is where I'm a little fuzzy. Here is where I configure my results controller, hopefully someone can help steer me in the right direction.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (nil != fetchedResultsController) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Homework" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasPet == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *dogDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"hasDog" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dogDescriptor, sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aController;

    // Release things

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Is a sort descriptor where I need to be focusing my attention?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's simple! Just provide the NSFetchedResultsController with a `sectionNameKeyPath` (which in this case would be `hasDog`) in its initializer.

The one caveat to this, however, is the section names will be `0` & `1` respectively, but it's easily curable.